# Move constructor not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
class X{
    unsigned int sz;
public:
    X(const unsigned int n = 0) : sz(n) {std::cout << "Default constructor called!" << std::endl;};
    X(const X& x) : sz(x.sz) {};
    X(X&& x) : sz(x.sz) {std::cout << "Move constructor called!" << std::endl;};
};

void foo(X&& x){
    std::cout << x.size() << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    X x(10);
    foo(std::move(x));
    foo(X(5));
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints:

> Default constructor called!
>   Default constructor called!

I am aware that the move constructor is pointless in this example, since we're not stealing anything, but shouldn't the move constructor still be called in these cases?

Edit: Using g++ 4.8.1 on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? You're just passing a rvalue reference to your function, not creating a new object.

```
X x(10); // default constructor
foo(std::move(x)); // passing x as an rvalue
foo(X(5)); // creating an object (with the default constructor) which is passed as an rvalue
```

Try `X y(std::move(x))` and your move constructor should be called.

The move constructor is only called when you create a new object using an rvalue reference.

Comment: "The move constructor is only called when you create a new object using an rvalue reference." - That explains it, thanks!